# Excel dynamic list with no blank cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table with data of 1000 rows and 10 columns.

From this table, I would like to create another table (on another sheet) that contains only rows with specified condition (e.g. one of the columns has a value 'TRUE').

But of course, I don't want to have table of 1000 rows with many blank rows. I would like a formula that skips all the blanks and gives me just a nice table of 50 rows (or how many fill the condition). I can do with the formula looking into one column for condition and returning value from another column (so I can VLOOKUP the rest of the columns).

I tried formula that I found [here](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2654-excel-dynamic-list-remove-blanks.html).

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$1000,MATCH(ROW()-ROW($A$1),$A$2:$A$1000,0)),"")
```

But when I copy the formula down, it doesn't skip the blank cells. It shows value based on condition correctly, but with blank rows in between.

Any idea if this can be done by sheet formulas?

Comment: You can avoid array formulas if you are willing to include a helper column.

Comment: Really? I can include a helper column, that is no problem.

Comment: Per forum rules, you need to post what you've tried so far.

Comment: Added non-working formula.