# Excel Dynamic List with no blanks

Tags: excel, list, dynamic

I have a list of products (1-10) for example and an Invoice for a customer.
I want to show which products are being bought on the invoice, based on a formula.
The only problem is that the customer might not buy all products. So for example they could buy product 1,5,6, I want to show 1 on the first row, 5 on the second and 6 on the third (no blanks in between).

[image: This is what I want]
<sub>(source: [biteconsulting.co.za](https://www.biteconsulting.co.za/images/wrong.png))</sub>

[image: This is what I'm getting]
<sub>(source: [biteconsulting.co.za](https://www.biteconsulting.co.za/images/right.png))</sub>

I have been fiddling with Index and Match as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47534989/excel-dynamic-list-with-no-blank-cells)  post, but I still get blank rows coming through. I know that I can loop through the invoice and delete blank rows, but I'd prefer not to do this (reusability issues).

I believe that Helper columns can work here. I have been using Helper columns for a long time (without realising that there was a term for them :) )
I often concatenate cells to do vlookups etc.

How would a helper column help here? What would I do? How would I do it?

Below is the list of products:

[Products](https://www.biteconsulting.co.za/images/products.png)

And below is the list of products that the client wants (blank rows are products that they didn't order (products 2 - 4,7-10):
[Ordered Products](https://www.biteconsulting.co.za/images/custprod.png)

Comment: would you open to using VBA?

Comment: What does your starting data look like? That will in part determine your options. And please share your current formula attempt.

Comment: Open to VBA definitely, just not deleting rows :)

Comment: Formula: =IFERROR(INDEX('Jan Calcs'!D$22:D$31,MATCH(ROW()-ROW($D$4),$A$5:$A$14,0)),"")
Jan Calcs D22:D31 contains 1,"","","","",5,6
A5:A14 contains:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10

Comment: It's not that clear from your screenshots how your data is arranged or where your formulas are...

Comment: Please show shot of source data. There are not enough values in 1,"","","","",5,6   to account for D22:D31 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so not exactly the solution, but it worked:
I basically listed all the values (blanks and all), and before printing, I checked if that cell was blank and if blank it hides the row.

```
For x = 1 To 300
  If Cells(x, 1) = "1" Then
    For z = x To x + 29
      If Cells(z, 2).Value = "" Then Rows(z).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Next
  End If
Next
```

Thanks for all the interest :)